# Tomcat Java - consumes 90% of the memory even when nobody is connected to the app

Tags: docker, tomcat, java

The tomcat instance is a docker image and it is consuming 90% of the host memory even when nobody is connected to the app. Only one instance of tomcat is running.

Is this normal? I've been testing docker container based tomcat instance to switch to kubernetes pods.

```
/usr/local/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -d64 -Xms4000m -Xmx4000m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ThreadStackSize=128k -Dtestserver.deployconfig=test.usrlocal -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Dhttps.proxySet=false -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

[image]

Comment: You say 90% but in the picture there's 59%. Moreover, the RSS is 1679MB while you set the heap size to 4000MB. You have to align your numbers. Furthermore, you seem to be using ancient java version (7?) because you have `-XX:MaxPermSize` in the cmd args (perm gen space has been removed in java 8). (especially in older versions) it's normal that jvm consumes some amount of memory and doesn't return much of it to the operating system afterwards. That doesn't mean all the memory is occupied - it's better to use java specific tools like jcmd, jstat, VisualVM, etc. to show more details.

Comment: Can you suggest a proper parameters to try with? I mean all the xmx, xms, etc.,.. I was running java 8 but had the options set.

Comment: I'm testing out `UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` options since this is in a docker container. Seems xms and xmx doesn't need to be set but it still consumes 700 MB

Comment: First, use more modern version like Java 14 if possible (you use docker, so it shouldn't be a problem unless you have a specific organizational policy). The `UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` setting isn't necessary in modern java versions, including later releases of Java 8 - JVM takes the docker host memory limit into account by default. As far as it goes to `-Xmx` setting the default (if you don't specify it) is 1/4 of the available memory. It depends how much you want to allocate but I wouldn't consider 700 MB to be much for Tomcat. What memory utilization do you expect?